# ContentControl in ControlTemplate does not show Border nor Background

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `Button` with a custom control template and a `Grid` as sibling. The Button should use the `TriangleUpPath` when the Grid is visible, otherwise it should use the `TriangleDownPath`. So far so good.

But I want that the `Path` has a `Border` around. So I thought I could just set the `BorderBrush` of the `ContentControl`, but this does not work. I don't see the Border. Same goes for the `Background` of the ContentControl.

Here is my minimal not working example:

```
<Button x:Name="_hideButton"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Click="ToggleResultsVisibility">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" >
            <Style.Resources>
                <Path x:Key="TriangleUpPath"
                            Data="M 0,5 L 7,0 L 14,5"
                            Margin="3,3,0,0"
                            Stroke="Black"
                            StrokeThickness="1"/>
                <Path x:Key="TriangleDownPath"
                            Data="M 0,0 L 7,5 L 14,0"
                            Margin="3,3,0,0"
                            Stroke="Black"
                            StrokeThickness="1"/>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Margin="0,5,5,0"
                                        Width="20" 
                                        Height="11" 
                                        BorderBrush="Magenta" 
                                        BorderThickness="1"
                                        Background="Cyan">
                            <ContentControl.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" 
                                            Value="HotPink"></Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=_resultsGrid}" 
                                                     Value="Collapsed">
                                            <Setter Property="Content" 
                                                    Value="{StaticResource TriangleDownPath}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=_resultsGrid}" 
                                                     Value="Visible">
                                            <Setter Property="Content" 
                                                    Value="{StaticResource TriangleUpPath}"/>
                                         </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ContentControl.Style>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
<Grid x:Name="_resultsGrid"/>
```

As you can see, I even tried to set the Background in the Style (to HotPink) to no avail.
It helps, when I have a Border around the ContentControl.

But the question is: why do the `Background`-Property and the `BorderBrush`-Property of the ContentControl have no influence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [default style for ContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334411(v=vs.95).aspx) does not contain a way of rendering the Border and Background properties, it just has a [ContentPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter(v=vs.110).aspx).

You need to add a custom template for the content control yourself, containing the additional elements you need:

```
<ContentControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
            <ContentPresenter
            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
            Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentControl.Template>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because BorderThickness/Brush aren't some magic properties that make the border magically appear out of nowhere.

For *making* borders, you should be using a `<Border>` element somewhere.

By default, the Button has some Border inside. That's why setting BorderBrush/BorderThickness on a Button does something. Specifically, the **default control template** of a Button contains a Border as one of its topmost elements, and that Border's definition looks similar to:

```
// the DEFAULT Button's control template
<ControlTemplate>
    ...
       <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
               BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
               .... >
                  ...here goes other things like textblock/content..
       </Border>
    ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

so, as you see, there's a border and it has its settings **bound to the owning control**, so bound to the Button. The TemplateBinding binds BBrush of Border to BBrush of the Button that owns it.

Now, as you have completely rewritten/overridden the Button's control template, it now does not contain any Border, so there is nothing that would draw the border.

Try:

```
    <Border BorderBrush=... BorderThickness=...>
       <ContentControl ....
```

and it should be like you wanted.

Afterthought: If I understood you wrong and if you meant your setting the BorderBrush/Thickness on the `ContentControl` inside the buttons' template that it didn't add border around your paths, then there's a surprise.

The properties are available on the CC only because they are commonly used, they came from base `Control` class. But the ContentControl does not use them at all. They are ignored. ContentControl does not draw any borders, texts, etc. ContentControl shows its content, and the content is just a Path which draws itself only. So, either add a Border around the ContentControl as above, or change your resources and wrap each Path into a Border and use that as a content resource.

```
        <Style.Resources>
            <Border x:Key="TriangleUpPath"
                    BorderBrush=... BorderThickness=...
               <Path Data="M 0,5 L 7,0 L 14,5"
                     .... />
            </Border>
            <Border x:Key="TriangleDownPath"
                    BorderBrush=... BorderThickness=...
               <Path Data="M 0,0 L 7,5 L 14,0"
                     .... />
            </Border>
        </Style.Resources>
```